# Java EE monitoring application

Tags: java, c++, jakarta-ee, jonas

I want to create an application with Java EE on a JONAS server for monitoring other applications and servers created with Java EE and C++.

So I'm looking for an API or something to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Java Management Extensions (JMX)? See a [brief description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html).

BTW there are quite a lot of tools (e.g., [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) by default in every JDK), are you sure you have to create a new monitor? I do not know your specific needs, but maybe you can use some existing tool for the job.

Comment: Hi thanls for the answer ,I cant use JConsole because i have to create a web application , for JMX is there any tutorial using a servlet or something ?

Comment: Hi, see my first link, it has some starting points (`new JMXServiceURL(...)`, see section *Connecting to the JMX Agent Programmatically*).